# How to test methods and state defined on the parent component

Tags: testing, reactjs

Consider the following react code:

```
export default class parentComponent extends Component {

    someFunc() {
        /* lots of logic */

        this.setState({
            foo: bar
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
           <div className="parent">
             <ChildComponent this.onSomeEvent={this.someFunc.bind(this)}>    </ChildComponent>
</div>
)
  }
}
```

I have a few questions around the best way to test the `someFunc` method:

1. How can I actually call the `someFunc` Method to test against it? When the code runs the method is called by `onSomeEvent` in the child component. With shallow rendering I only have access to `parentComponent`.
2. All of the shallow rendering examples I've looked at show how to test a component based on props passed to it. The only way I can think to test the `parentComponent` is to examine it's state as methods are called. When `someFunc` is called it updates the state. Can examining state be done with shallow rendering? I can't find any examples of this.